# Count two columns from 1 table

Tags: mysql, sql

I got this table (date, indoor_km, outdoor_km,...)

[image]

I have found the SQL count to count `indoor_km` or `outdoor_km`
but I'm looking for a SQL count for the 2 columns from 1 table.

Comment: You want individual counts? Or sum of both columns?

Comment: Needs to be clarified to be answered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You simply add them

```
SELECT SUM(indoor_km) + SUM(outdoor_km)
FROM...
```

To select the sum only for a time period simply add a `WHERE` clause, either using `BETWEEN` or `>=, <=`, I used the latter in my example

```
SELECT SUM(indoor_km) + SUM(outdoor_km)
FROM Fietsen_2018
WHERE datum >= '1/01/2018' AND datum <='31/01/2018'
```

Comment: how can i select sum from date range 1/01/2018 to 31/01/2018

SELECT datum, indoor_km FROM `Fietsen_2018` WHERE datum = '1/01/2018'
this only shows 1/01/2018

when i use code

SELECT datum, indoor_km FROM `Fietsen_2018` WHERE datum BETWEEN '1/01/2018' AND '31/01/2018'

datum indoor_km 
1/01/2018
2/01/2018   12.32
3/01/2018
10/01/2018  10.68
11/01/2018
29/01/2018
30/01/2018  10.22
31/01/2018
1/02/2018
2/02/2018

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SUM` function over a condition in order to count entries that satisfy your condition of `IS NOT NULL`:

```
select
    sum( case when indoor_km is not null then 1 else 0 end ) As indoorKmCount, 
    sum( case when outdoor_km is not null then 1 else 0 end ) As outdoorKmCount
from table
```

Comment: now it count the amount of rows (365 ) the amount of days in one year. it need to sum the values from indoor_km and from outdoor_km

Comment: select
    sum(indoor_km) As indoorKmsum, 
    sum(outdoor_km) As outdoorKmsum
from Fietsen_2018

this count the values in the cells , what i want is the sum off the values

Comment: In your question you specifically asked about the count, not the sum. You should edit that.